# Drupal MySQL multiple tables, multiple conditions return table column data which matches a keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, drupal

How to create a query that selects or joins multiple table and returns column that only match the condition keyworkd.

I have table1 'field_title_table'

```
entityid | field_title     | entitytype
---------------------------------------        
413      | WELCOME TO the USA  |   page_hub
```

table2  'field_description_table'

```
entityid | field_description     | entitytype
---------------------------------------------        
413      | Land of the free and  |   page_hub
```

I tried below steps

```
$query = db_select('field_title_table', 'wb');
$query->join('field_description_table','sd','sd.entityid = wb.entityid');
$query->fields('wb',array('field_title'));
$query->fields('sb',array('field_description'));

 $db_or = db_or();              
 $db_or->condition('wb.field_title,'%'.$keyword.'%','LIKE');
 $db_or->condition('sb.field_description,'%'.$keyword.'%','LIKE');
 $query->condition($db_or);
 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

The `$keyword` can be anything. So if `$keyword` were to be 'land', I wanted only the result '*Land of the free and* ' to be returned from the `field_description` table, but I get both field_title value and field_description value regardless of my `$keyword` only matching on one table.

So basically I want this

```
SELECT field_title from field_title_table WHERE field_title LIKE '%$keyword%'

SELECT field_description from field_description_table WHERE field_description LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

without having multiple SELECT's

So my desired output would be

if I have the keyword as `welcome` then ouput should be

```
[field_title] => WELCOME TO THE USA (field_title_table)
[field_description]=> '' (field_description_table)
```

if I have the keyword as `land` then ouput should be

```
[field_title] => '' (field_title_table)
[field_description]=> 'Land of the free and' (field_description_table)
```

if I have the keyword as `the` then ouput should be

```
[field_title] => WELCOME TO the USA (field_title_table)
[field_description]=> 'Land of the free and' (field_description_table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query you want :

```
SELECT A.filed_title,B.field_description 
FROM field_title_table A,field_description_table B
WHERE A.entityid =B.entityid  
AND (A.filed_title LIKE '%your_keyword%' OR B.field_description LIKE '%your_keyword%' )
```

I tested it and worked

i think i got what u expect , well you can't do you condition in query so you have to do it with a stored procedure where you will exec your query and filter the result

well there is a way around using php to filter your result

```
<?php

// your query 
$key="/".$keyword."/";
foreach($result AS $row){

     if(preg_match($key,$row['field_title']))
     {
       echo 'field title =>' .$row['field_title'];
       echo 'filed_description => \'\' ';
     }else{
       echo 'field title => \'\' ';
       echo 'filed_description => '.$row['field_description'];
     }

}



?>
```

Comment: I tried this and it is exactly the problem I had, I dont want fields that does not have the keyword as if it were two select queries.

Comment: give us what you want as output

Comment: i think i got what u expect , well you can't do you condition in query so you have to do it with a stored procedure where you will exec your query and filter the result

Comment: Thank you, your answer will work post query with manipulating the result, I was wondering if it were possible within the query itself. I will be marking your answer as the solution but will wait 24 hours for  anything new, but by the looks of it looks like yours is the only solution.